# One Android project two java file & res file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I took this from another resource but I have two `java` files and a `res` file I could not understand very well. Are these two files necessary?

**[image: Android project]**

Comment: `autoimageslider` is a different module, probably a **library** on which your main app depends for additional features.

Comment: @DarShan ok Fine so if we keep a file can there be a problem

Comment: There's not going to be a problem. You can read more about modules here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects

Answer (score 0):

its a **modular** project.

in modular project, for every android-library module you have a manifest, java folder and res folder

your main manifest is the one in **app** module. you can navigate among activities as well.
for more information about modular project benefits check [this](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/03/06/modularizationwhy/) link